# Blazor component isolated css with tailwind/postcss

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, postcss

**Is it possible to use tailwind and postcss syntax for blazor component isolated css?**

I really like Tailwind as a CSS framework specifically its use of postcss and the `@apply` functionality where you can bundle tailwinds css components into an individual class.

e.g.

```
.some-button {
    @apply px-4 py-2 bg-blue-400 text-white
}
```

I've been considering using Svelte because it offers both CSS isolation and postcss @apply syntax. However now that Blazor supports isolated CSS I would really like to take it a small step further and be able to write postcss styles from within component CSS.

So... any idea if that's possible yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible!** *Tested with .NET 5.0*

You have to create a new npm project in the projects root directory.

1. Use `npm init` to create a new npm project.
2. Add the dependencies of tailwind and postcss with `npm i -D postcss-cli autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss`
3. Add a config for postcss

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

4. Add the tailwind.config.js to the project using `npx tailwindcss init`.
   If needed, you can replace the purge property to remove unused css classes. *But this was a bit buggy in my tests when I used a Razor library*.

```
// tailwind.config.js
purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
        './**/*.html',
        './**/*.razor',
        './**/*.razor.css'
    ],
},
```

5. Add a post-css buildscript to your *.csproj* file. This will apply postcss rules to the stylesheets bundled by Blazor after each build.

**For Blazor projects:**

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npx postcss $(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0\scopedcss\bundle\$(ProjectName).styles.css -r" />
</Target>
```

**For Blazor component libraries:**

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npx postcss $(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0\scopedcss\projectbundle\$(ProjectName).bundle.scp.css -r" />
</Target>
```

I'm not sure why the path differs, I can't find any documentation to it. If someone knows more, feel free to reply.

If there's anything that doesn't make sense or could be done better, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks so much for your input on this, it works perfectly when using a standard Blazor web project without a component library or compiling a component library directly. However I think there's an issue when a web project references a component library. It seems the very first line of the component lib compiled  CSS has `@import '';` which I think confuses the postcss process, any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: I'm just getting started but it seems to work for .NET 6 as well! I replaced `net5.0` with `$(TargetFramework)` to make it more agnostic.

Comment: did you try with dotnet 8 RC1?